# Sharing (JPA) Business Entities across EARs on a glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I deploy several EARs in my glassfish 3.1.2 instance. I would like to be able to hand over a BE from a class in EAR A to a class in EAR B - implying that class B can update the BE.

Is this even possible? How to configure the persistence.xmls to make this work?

All information I found on the web focuses on sharing between modules (jar, war) in one application (ear). I want to share between modules in different ears (war A in ear B fetches a BE from jar C in ear D).

**Update:**
I doubt myself that what I am trying to achieve here is good design or best practise. The whole story is that I am migrating an application from JEE5 and Weblogic 10 to JEE6 on Glassfish 3. It used to run fine in the old environment without any special setup. Now Glassfish "nulls" all values of the BE that is passed to a class in the other EAR.

If I pack all jars and wars in one EAR it runs fine, but I loose the intended packaging structure. I hoped there might be a way without removing the underlaying coupling of the two components.

Answer (score 0):

You could pack your entities in a utility jar, and have both ears include this jar in their lib folder.

For each persistence.xml you can use `<jar-file>` element to include the entities.

For example

```
 <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="xxx">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
        <jta-data-source>xxx</jta-data-source>      
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <jar-file>lib/entities.jar</jar-file>       

        <properties>
            xxx
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

After that, you could pass around the entities using remote ejb lookups.

Not sure If I would advise this.. Do you need to share the exact entities? Can't you use dto's and delegate the responsablility of persistence to only one app?

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Sadly this did not work for me. You are certainly right to advise a better design :) I just hoped for an easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you the structure of my projects where I have several. War and EJB module shared by all.

**first**: must create a project library where you should declare your EJB remote interfaces and your utility classes (ex: clintLib.jar).

**second**: in your EJB module you must use the clientLib.jar as lib. Add there your entities.

**third**: In your war module you must use the clientLib.jar as lib.

This way you have access to your EJB module from any war through remote interfaces declared in clientLib.jar. The EJB container will provide access to lookup EJB instances using transparent to you. my app structure is: 3 war 1 library project 1 EJB project

Comment: I am not trying to share between jars and wars inside one ear, but rather between two separate ears.